# Regarding not loading component in order Angular with Lazyload Routing

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using lazyload routing in our application! I'm facing strange issue as follows

I have AppModule in side that TopModule and then DashboardModule and all are loaded in lazyload

if someone open localhost:4200/dashboard then it loads in order of Appmodule,Topmodule DashboardModule and TopComponent

but it should loads in order of Appmodule,Topmodule,TopComponent and DashboardModule

As Dashboard Module is getting loaded Before TopComponent because of it my page is getting stucked!

NOTE : I have used  in all modules where routing are defined!

My code is as follows

**app.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";

 const appRoutes: Routes = [     
   {
      path: '',
      loadChildren: './top.module#TopModule',
   }     
 ];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)      
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**top.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { TopComponent } from './top.component';
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: TopComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: './first.module#FirstModule',
        },
        {
            path: 'dashboard',
            loadChildren: './dashboard.module#DashboardModule',

        },
    ]
}
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TopComponent         
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [],
})

export class TopModule {
}
```

**top.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: You're not loading your page modules lazily. Try using the following notation: `loadChildren: () => import('./list/list.module').then(m => m.ListModule)`. See https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MP.Web/ClientApp/src/app/pages/medium-type/medium-type-routing.module.ts

Comment: Should TopComponent appear in all views ?

Comment: Also, generate a module per page, in order not to load modules for all pages `ng g module list --module top --route top`

Comment: @Pieterjan yes we have created modules per functionality and inside that every page has its components

Comment: @AmadouBeye yes it has html structure of our application

Comment: Apparently the '/list.module.ts#ListModule' notation is still okay for lazy-loading, so I was wrong... https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: yes.. I have also crated separate project for import but sill issue persists

Comment: probably because your `AppModule ` and `TopModule` has the same `path: '' ` ? 
try redirecting it and add some path to it `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'base', pathMatch: 'full' }` and `{ path: 'base',   loadChildren: './top.module#TopModule',  }` in your `AppModule`

Comment: @timnaire That is also tried still not got sucess

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as you stated in comment above, if TopComponent should appear in all view, it doesn't make sense to load it lazyly. You should add TopModule to your AppModule because users will get it no matter the url they enter.

Next, to load `FirstModule` and `DashboardModule` lazyly you can do it as below:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: OutletComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: './first.module#FirstModule',
        },
        {
            path: 'dashboard',
            loadChildren: './dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
        },
    ]
}]
```

And finally create a component for childrens routing:

```
//OutletComponent

@Component({
    selector: 'outlet-component',
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
})
export class OutletComponent {}
```

Comment: @amdoue thanks as for update let me correct TopComponent should load for its child and did the same thing which you have suggested as you see the example but still it doesn't work 
FYI! i have created sample separete application in Angular 12 it has same behaviour:(

Thanks